# Invalid Qualifier - Using string.Replace() function

Tags: string, vba

I have been hitting Google for a while, this one is getting plain frustrating now as I can't seem to fix it. I keep getting Invalid Qualifier when trying to use the `String.Replace()` function.

I am trying to create a file name for storing a PDF document but there are a few exceptions where the Ref# in the table have `/`'s in them. My code is as follows

```
Dim tempRef As String
...    
tempRef = recordSet("Ref#")
MyFileName = MyPath & tempRef.Replace("/", "") & ".pdf"
```

Unsure why but I keep getting the "invalid qualifier" error for executing this function.

Apologies for simplicity of this one...

Comment: @Eray thanks mate, that worked. Was using [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxbw3kwc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1](this site) as reference, can't understand why that wouldn't be noted... Cheers mate

Comment: You are very welcome, buddy. I will be glad if you select my answer as the correct answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try:

```
MyFileName = MyPath & Replace(tempRef, "/", "") & ".pdf"
```